# Looking for options to reduce Logger.LogInformation latency

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-application-insights

I am using Application Insight to monitor my aspnet core application.

It takes 5-10 seconds to see Logger.LogInformation entries in the Application Insight search.

I like to see my log entries faster.

What are my options to reduce the latency?

**Update 1**

I understand that the delay is by design and it there will be delay no matter what.

This question is to find techniques to reduce the delay.

I expect there should be options when I call `builder.Services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry();` that reduces (no eliminate, just reduce) the telemetry delay.

Comment: [The delay issue caused by design](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/faq#how-long-does-it-take-for-telemetry-to-be-collected-).

Answer (score 0):

- Telemetry (App Insights) data takes some time like 10 Seconds, 2 min, 5 minutes also as mentioned in this  [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/faq#how-long-does-it-take-for-telemetry-to-be-collected-).
- But it also depends on the size of data sending to the Application Insights.
- Actual process in the backend of sending the telemetry data to App Insights resource is, it collects and aggregates the data like ingestion, processing the data, indexing them and storing accordingly.
- You can use the [Live Metrics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net-core?tabs=netcore6#live-metrics) Stream option in the Application Insights resource with less latency but with the less data logs (telemetry).

[image]